# Labels Force Layout d3 js

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I've attached text to gnodes in the force layout like this.

```
var gnodes = svg.selectAll('g.gnode')
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter()
.append('g')
.classed('gnode', true);

var labels = gnodes.append("text")
.attr("dx", 5)
.attr("dy", 5)
.attr("font-size","1.5em")
.text("");
```

What I'd like to do is loop through all gnodes and selectively (on the basis of node.index) change the text of some of the corresponding labels. I'm not sure how I'd do that?

```
labels.text("text", function(d) {
    console.log("gnode Object d is " + d);
    return "a function for this text";
});
```

This doesn't work. I'd appreciate any help. For those wanting the whole code, here it [is](http://plnkr.co/edit/iXnTAhfGNgVY8OPHBBRm).

Comment: It's `.text(function(d) { ... })`, not `.text("text", ...)`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, thanks! I got the labels to display stuff on the console but the text for some reason is displayed on the top left corner of the window instead of adjacent to the nodes. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I'll refer you to the [working example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642) again. Please work from that.

Comment: I got it, it turns out that I was updating the node (circle) and not the gnode in the tick function, fixing that fixed the labels, though why exactly I'm not sure. Thanks anyway!